# Getting user's location for google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So I'm trying to have google maps with direction service It works fine until I try to get the user's location to use as a start point. The idea is to give a user directions from their current location to one of the three. I have been following along with some guides on on Google's API.

When I try to get the user's location I try using:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var position = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        googleCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);


        }

        else {
            alert("No geolocation!");
        }
```

But for some reason this breaks the map? Trying to get the user's coordinates in a variable to use in the Directions services and as an origin for the map. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Displaying text directions with <code>setPanel()</code></title>
<style>

  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  #right-panel {
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  #right-panel select {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #right-panel i {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  #right-panel {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    width: 390px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #map {
    margin-right: 400px;
  }
  #floating-panel {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
    display: none;
  }
  @media print {
    #map {
      height: 500px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #right-panel {
      float: none;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="floating-panel">
  <strong>Start:</strong>
  <select id="start">

    <option value="USERLOCATION">Your location</option>

  </select>
  <br>
  <strong>End:</strong>
  <select id="end">
    <option value="memorial university of newfoundland">St. John's 
Campus</option>
    <option value="marine insitute of memorial university of 
newfoundland">Marine Insitute</option>
    <option value="grenfell campus">Grenfell Campus</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var lat = null;
    var long = null;
    var googleCoords = null;
  function initMap() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        googleCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
 position.coords.longitude);


        }

        else {
            alert("No geolocation!");
        }


    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

    var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
    control.style.display = 'block';
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', 
onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', 
onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    directionsService.route({
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
  </body>
```

Comment: the code you have posted seems ok, i think the issue is some where else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do into a function getCurrentPosition.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get the position from callback function like this.

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var googleCoords = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
```